# Vue how do you select all the text in a component with a computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can normally select all the text with `$event.target.select()` but in this case I think it is selecting all and then replacing the selection with the computed property. How do you select all after the computed property is finished?

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `
<div>
My Component
<input type="text" v-model="displayValue" @blur='isInputActive = false' @focus='isInputActive = true;$event.target.select()'></input>
</div>
`,
  props:['value'],
    data() {
        return {
            isInputActive: false
        };
    },
    computed: {
        displayValue: {
            get: function() {            
                return (this.isInputActive) ? this.value : this.value.toUpperCase();
            },
            set: function(val) {
              this.$emit('input', val);
            },
        }
    },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
        return {
            test: "Test"
        };
    },  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component v-model="test"></my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$nextTick` which run the callback after the computed property is finished.

```
@focus='isInputActive = true; $nextTick(() => $event.target.select())'
```